# Monero GUI Beta 2 Window Covering Entire Screen (Linux, Arch x64)

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, linux

When running the Beta 2 release of GUI on Arch Linux x64 the window is too big and it covers my entire screen! What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

It's already fixed in the [code](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/commit/05084422a5a0232993abb269b39954cca7708d01) and you could re-build the GUI with that fix. Next release shouldn't have this problem.

In the meantime, and if you want to avoid re-building, you can edit the `start-gui.sh` script which came with the package and add the line `export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0`. Then, open the GUI by running `./start-gui.sh` from the console.

After modification, the `start-gui.sh` file should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`/libs
export QT_PLUGIN_PATH=`pwd`/plugins
export QML2_IMPORT_PATH=`pwd`/qml
./monero-wallet-gui
```